# Ansatz Dimensionality Reduction Argument

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading a book by *Cartea & Jaimungal* and on *page 145* they claim the following:

We want to solve the following PDE: for $t \in [0,T]$
$$0=(\partial _t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\partial_{ss})H-\phi q^2+\frac{1}{4K}\frac{\Big[(s\partial_x-b\partial_s-\partial_q)H\Big]^2}{\partial_xH}$$
with final condition $$H(T,x,s,q)=x+sq-\alpha q^2.$$

We make the ansatz for the solution to a PDE:
$$H(t,x,s,q)=x+sq+h(t,s,q)$$$$ h(T,s,q)=-\alpha q^2.$$

Upon substituting this ansatz into the PDE, we get

$$0=(\partial _t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\partial_{ss})h-\phi q^2+\frac{1}{4K}\Big[b(q+\partial_s h)+\partial_q h\Big]^2.$$

So far so good. But now they claim that since the PDE does not depend on $s$ and that the final condition is independent of $s$, it is enough to conclude that $\partial_sh(t,s,q)=0$ and so we can simplify the ansatz even further to $$H(t,x,s,q)=x+sq+g(t,q),$$ where $h(t,s,q)=g(t,q).$

Is there any intuition behind this? I cannot understand how the above two things mean that $h$ will be independent of the variable $s$.

Comment: I am a bit confused, you define $h$ to be independent of $s$, i.e. $h(T,s,q)=h(q)=-\alpha q^2$, and then you are surprised that $h$ is independent of $s$? Maybe I just do not understand your question right.

Comment: My thoughts were that in the book they defined the initial guess to be as general as possible by including $s$ inside of $h$ but then I didn’t get their argument to claim that $h$ is independent of $s$. I don’t see how the two facts lead to this independence... is that always true? I just wanted some help on their way of deducing a solution which I think is more an art sometimes over systematic reasoning. Obviously their reasoning is correct as it leads to a solution which ends up being unique but I wouldn’t know how to make their guess of $x+ sq+h(t,s,q)$.

Comment: You are absolutely right in stating that finding the correct Ansatz is an art. However, there is something to keep in mind. You want to reduce the order, so in stead of studying the infinite dimensional PDE, you hope to study the simpler finite dimensional ODE. Hence, it makes sense to assume that $h$ does not depend on $s$ or $t$ to simplify you problem. Often, only after endless computations and wrong assumptions, you discover what the `right' Ansatz was, and often then it becomes clear why it had to be that way.